# How to iterate through json with variable keys and get the key value?

Tags: node.js

I've tried using a `foreach` loop, using `Object` properties. using bracket notation, none of these give me what I need. I want to store `TT_pistol_(gold)` as a variable, and have all the data related to it in another variable. I can't use data['TT_pistol_(gold)'] because it varies in name.

ex. input

```
{  
"TT_pistol_(gold)":{  
    "weight":0,
    "recoil":750,
    "ergonomics":75,
    "RPM":30,
    "Caliber":"7.62x25mm_Tokarev"
  }
}
```

ex. output
name = 'TT_pistol_(gold)';
data = '{
        "weight":0,
        "recoil":750,
        "ergonomics":75,
        "RPM":30,
        "Caliber":"7.62x25mm_Tokarev"
      }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
'use strict';

const obj = {
  "TT_pistol_(gold)":{
    "weight":0,
    "recoil":750,
    "ergonomics":75,
    "RPM":30,
    "Caliber":"7.62x25mm_Tokarev"
  }
};

for (const [name, data] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(name);
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had to wrap it in an array,forEach so that it would work with multiple in an array. Thanks!